Would Acid Fog dissolve the opponent's equipment?
It says "the fog deals 2d6 points of acid damage to each creature and object within it", and I wonder if the "object" includes the objects that those creatures are holding/equipping/etc. (aka "attended object").
It would be ideal if an official conclusion is provided. I did some research but didn't find a clear conclusion.
I personally think it is reasonable for damaging all objects regardless attended or not (but all glass and most crystal should survive and be immune to Acid damage, based on what my Chemistry teacher told me), and it is logical to have all potions naturally contained in acid-proof container like glass bottles. All other objects shall be affected unless they have a container to take damage for them.
Meanwhile, it seems for RAI and gaming experience perspective, only unattended objects and characters should take damage, not the attended objects. Otherwise it would be too powerful as a spell. (Then it seems I need to rewrite the spell description and update with my PCs.)
UPDATE:
There's a rule saying that:

Unless the descriptive text for the spell specifies otherwise, all items carried or worn by a creature are assumed to survive a magical attack. If a creature rolls a natural 1 on its saving throw against the effect, however, an exposed item is harmed (if the attack can harm objects).

The issues of applying this rule here are:
Firstly, this spell has no saving throw.
Secondly, it "specifies otherwise".

Each round on your turn, starting when you cast the spell, the fog deals 2d6 points of acid damage to each creature and object within it.

It didn't limit its effect to unattended objects. I wonder if we can use a more strict reading that "if it didn't specify, 'objects' are just unattended objects" or a broader reading that "if it didn't specify, 'objects' are all objects regardless of attended or not".
Referencing:

the 6th level spell that destroyed our party (Acid Fog)

Acid Fog and items

Acid Fog and their effect on attended objects



Are carried and worn objects damaged by magical attacks?
Sometimes, but not often. The rules for this are found on page 177 of the Player's Handbook, under the heading "Items Surviving after a Saving Throw."

Unless the descriptive text for the spell specifies otherwise, all items carried or worn by a creature are assumed to survive a magical attack. If a creature rolls a natural 1 on its saving throw against the effect, however, an exposed item is harmed (if the attack can harm objects). Refer to Table 10-1: Items Affected by Magical Attacks. Determine which four objects carried or worn by the creature are most likely to be affected and roll randomly among them. The randomly determined item must make a saving throw against the attack form and take whatever damage the attack deals (see Smashing an Object, page 165).

The accompanying table lists items that could potentially be affected in order from most to least likely.
These rules are straightforward, but rarely have much impact on play. Between natural ones being rare, only one item being affected per attack, the items at the top of the table all being relatively durable, and the item getting a saving throw and getting to use its hardness and HP to resist, it's fairly rare for items to actually get broken in combat; in all my years of GMing 3.5rd edition, I think I've only ever seen it come up once. I imagine many groups find it easier to ignore this rule entirely.
Does acid fog, specifically, affect carried and worn objects?
No. The rules I quoted above are clear and unambiguous: Magical attacks only damage carried or worn items if the descriptive text for the spell says it does, or if an attacked creature rolls a natural 1 on their saving throw. Acid fog meets neither of those conditions.
Acid fog does not require or allow a saving throw, so there are few to no situations in which a character could roll a natural 1 on their saving throw against it. The rules mention no special exceptions for spells that do not allow a saving throw, so such a spell can only damage carried or worn objects if its descriptive text says that it can.
There is nothing in the descriptive text of the acid fog spell to indicate that it is meant to be an exception to the general rule for magical attacks affecting worn and carried items. The spell's descriptive text does say that the cloud affects "each creature and object within it" without using the word "unattended," but that's nothing unusual: Many other spells that affect an area (incendiary cloud, lightning bolt, et cetera) also do not explicitly specify that their effect on objects only applies to unattended objects. This is to be expected; the whole point of having a general rule is to save having to repeat the same information in every part of the rules to which it applies. As such, it's safe to assume that the general rule for magical attacks damaging carried and worn objects applies to every spell that does not explicitly say otherwise.
There are relatively few spells that do explicitly call out that they affect carried and worn objects (presumably because such spells tend to require painful bookkeeping), but I was able to find one example: Transmute metal to wood, which starts with "This spell enables you to change all metal objects within its area to wood." Like acid fog, this line doesn't include the word "unattended" - and yet the very next line is "Weapons, armour, and other metal objects carried by creatures are affected as well." That additional sentence is necessary because the absence of "unattended" alone is not enough to indicate that the spell affects carried things; if it were not necessary, there would be no reason for it to be included.
Is this what the game designers intended?
Maybe? They're not currently taking questions, so we can't just ask. As such, all we have to go on is the rules that they wrote - and the rules that they wrote are clear and unambiguous on this point.
It's certainly possible that they didn't take acid fog into account when writing the general rule for magical attacks affecting carried or worn objects; 3.5 is a complicated beast of a system, and no mortal could account for every possible interaction of its rules. But a lot of things are possible. If we start speculating that "maybe the designers meant something other than what they wrote" there'd be no end to it; in the absence of evidence to the contrary, we must assume that they wrote what they meant and meant what they wrote if we want the rules to be reliable for any practical purpose.

Yes. When parsing 3.5 rules, assume there are no missing words- because there aren't.
Shy of finding an errata printed somewhere that changes the exact wording of the spell, 3.5 - and all of 3.X in general- is a completed edition that no longer receives updates or rulings. It is as complete as it is ever going to get. If it doesn't say a specific type of object- for example, unattended- then no adjectives exist, and it's all objects.
With that said, by its closing, 3.x had tons of material, so it's a fair ask to wonder if there are any corollary rules printed elsewhere in the book to address this. Looking to the SRD under Carrying, Movement, & Exploration > Exploration, there's a subsection called "Breaking and Entering" that's sort of punnish(ing) - it deals with Smashing objects and a small plethora of rules dealing with dealing damage to objects.
You can find them here.
The highlights for your topic are;

Hardness. Each object has hardness—a number that represents how well it resists damage. Whenever an object takes damage, subtract its hardness from the damage. Only damage in excess of its hardness is deducted from the object’s hit points (see Table: Common Armor, Weapon, and Shield Hardness and Hit Points; Table: Substance Hardness and Hit Points; and Table: Object Hardness and Hit Points).

Note that this point is important to your topic because unless otherwise stated, the type of damage here is irrelevant.

Hit Points. An object’s hit point total depends on what it is made of and how big it is (see Table: Common Armor, Weapon, and Shield Hardness and Hit Points; Table: Substance Hardness and Hit Points; and Table: Object Hardness and Hit Points). When an object’s hit points reach 0, it’s ruined. Very large objects have separate hit point totals for different sections.


Energy Attacks. Acid and sonic attacks deal damage to most objects just as they do to creatures; roll damage and apply it normally after a successful hit. Electricity and fire attacks deal half damage to most objects; divide the damage dealt by 2 before applying the hardness. Cold attacks deal one-quarter damage to most objects; divide the damage dealt by 4 before applying the hardness.

This lets you know that acid specifically does normal damage on objects (ignore hardness), as opposed to multiple other types that don't.

Magic Armor, Shields, and Weapons. Each +1 of enhancement bonus adds 2 to the hardness of armor, a weapon, or a shield and +10 to the item’s hit points.

This reminds you that magic things are harder to destroy than nonmagical ones.

Damaged Objects A damaged object remains fully functional until the item’s hit points are reduced to 0, at which point it is destroyed. Damaged (but not destroyed) objects can be repaired with the Craft skill.

This lets you know how to handle damaged items; you don't, except to keep track of their HP until they're broken. They're like PC's; 1 HP is good enough to swing like 1000.

This answer does not mention the rules for carried and worn items being damaged by magical attacks laid out in the PHB, and is therefore hugely misleading. -1.

To add to the previous comment, acid attacks ignoring hardness are also questionable at best. The section talks about division of the damage specifically, so acid just does x1 damage to objects, as it does to creatures (hardness and resistances, most probably, applying normally).

@annoyingimp Acid and Sonic specifically state they do normal damage as they do to creatures. Creatures don't have hardness. Every other energy type mentioned then mentions applying hardness, uniquely leaving Acid and Sonic devoid of that detail. ---> I'm aware of the FAQ covering RAI but FAQs aren't Errata, so RAW unless creatures normally have hardness, then I don't see how my reading is any more questionable than yours.

@GMJoe Given that the OP specifically wanted me to exclude information relating to saving throws (acid fog has none) that seemed even less relevant than the bit they already had me pull from the original text of my answer, since the descriptive text for the spell specifies otherwise, and there's no saving throw anyway. I don't see what's misleading about it.

Check 3.0 section energy attacks. Would cold ignore hardness in this edition? I mean, it just illustrates, authors may skip a mention of hardness from time to time. As the thing is obvious enough.

Page 177 of the Player's Handbook states:

Items Surviving after a Saving Throw.
Unless the descriptive text for the spell specifies otherwise, all items carried or worn by a creature are assumed to survive a magical attack.

The spell states:

Each round on your turn, starting when you cast the spell, the fog deals 2d6 points of acid damage to each creature and object within it.

Using the "Specific beats General" rule:

There is a general rule that items carried or worn by a creature are assumed to survive magical attacks.
There is a specific rule for the Acid Fog spell that it damages each creature and (each) object within the fog.

The GM can rule several possible ways:

The spell states that it damages each object and, since specific beats general, then each object takes damage (including carried and worn objects since the spell specifically calls out "each" object rather than "each unattended" object).
The spell states that it damages each object but does not explicitly mention carried or worn objects so we can apply both rules at the same time and assume that carried and worn items survive. Therefore, the spell effectively only damages each creature and each non-carried, non-worn object.

There is an argument that either interpretation is valid and it is up to the GM to determine which they are applying.
If you go for the first option, having one spell destroy most of a party's equipment or eliminate all the loot from an encounter may not be fun. However, with agreement from everyone at the table, it could be an interesting plot twist if it is used sparingly.

Yeah, it is up to GM's decision. The problem is, I am the GM =_=
